# How to add custom media gallery upload functionality in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I need to add a custom multiple image upload functionality in magento 2... How to add it in admin side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below link if you want to add it in your custom module.

[Magento2: How can we implement multiple image upload functionality](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167708/magento2-how-can-we-implement-multiple-image-upload-functionality)